# Async функция в app.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

Задача: Необходимо возвращать с сервера некоторые данные в ответ на get запрос.
Есть функция, которая возвращает массив, с ссылками на картинки. Если вызывать функцию вне app.get() - функция отрабатывает корректно и возвращает необходимый массив, однако массив естественно не обновляется,  при очередном обращении к адресу. Соответственно необходимо вызывать функцию внутри app.get(), что бы массив обновлялся.
Понимаю, что необходимо использовать промисы/коллбэки, но все никак не получается. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

```
// function to create an array of links to images    
function createImagesUrl() {
        const images = []
        fs.readdir("./upload", { withFileTypes: true },
            (err, files) => {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err)
                else {
                    files.forEach(file => {
                        if (path.extname(file.name) === ".jpg") {
                            var imgpath = '/upload/' + file.name
                            images.push(imgpath)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        return images
    }
    const imagesUrl = createImagesUrl()

 // get random background images from the server
    app.get("/uploads", (req, res) => {
        res.send(imagesUrl)
        console.log(imagesUrl)
    })
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// function to create an array of links to images    
function getImagesUrls( callback ) {
    const arr = [];
    fs.readdir("./upload", { withFileTypes: true }, (err, files) => {
        if (err){
            callback(err);
        } else {
            files.forEach( file => {
                if (path.extname(file.name) === ".jpg") {
                    var imgpath = '/upload/' + file.name;
                    arr.push(imgpath);
                }
            })
            callback( null, arr );
        }
    });
}

// get random background images from the server
app.get("/uploads", (req, res) => {
    getImagesUrls(( err, arr )=>{
        if( err ){
            res.send('error');
        } else {
            res.send( JSON.stringify(arr) );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! :)